# How to convert Snowflake function in spark Datafreame?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake, I am able to run this query just fine:

```
select business_month 
from table1
where business_month between TO_VARCHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('202308', 'YYYYMM'),6), 'YYYYMM')
                         and TO_VARCHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('202406', 'YYYYMM'),12), 'YYYYMM');
```

When I run it in spark, I get this error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Undefined function: 'TO_VARCHAR'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 193 pos 23"
```

Here is my code:

```
DF = spark.sql ("""
select business_month 
from table1
where business_month between TO_VARCHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('202308', 'YYYYMM'),6), 'YYYYMM')
                         and TO_VARCHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('202406', 'YYYYMM'),12), 'YYYYMM'
""");

DF.createOrReplaceTempView('TEST_TABLE')
```

I am assuming spark doesnt have that function built in. Is there a way to replicate the logic to make it compatible with spark?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CAST` instead of `TO_VARCHAR` (I also think that `TO_DATE` probably needs to be changed to `DATEADD`, and I don't think `YYYYMM` is a supported format in SQL, but `YYYYMMDD` is supported so we'll have to hardcode the day for your dates, and I chose the first day of the month).

```
DF = spark.sql ("""
select business_month 
from table1
where business_month between CAST(DATEADD(month, 6, CAST('20230801' AS DATE)) AS VARCHAR)
                         and CAST(DATEADD(month, 12, CAST('20240601' AS DATE)) AS VARCHAR)
""");
```